# How can a Netty TCP Client verify that its message was received?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, netty

I am writing a TCP Client application using Netty v4.1.5, and would like to ensure that it knows whether its messages have been received by the next hop. For reference, I define ‘message’ as an application-level message, and 'packet' as a TCP packet. A message can be composed of one or more packets.

I encountered a very similar question on stack overflow here ([TCP Netty Ensure message received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282252/tcp-netty-ensure-message-received)), but it was asked years ago, and I’m not sure I agree with the answers. TCP is a reliable network protocol, so the sender can determine whether a given packet was delivered to its destination successfully. If the application were synchronous, it could maintain a mapping between the original message, and the packets it was divided into. The map might look something like this:

Message 1 → (p1, p2,… pN)

Message 2 → (pN+1, pN+2, … pN+M)

Using this map, the sending application could infer which message was not delivered whenever a packet is not delivered. Unfortunately, making this determination becomes much more difficult in an asynchronous world. The application’s ‘send’ method makes no guarantee that the message is delivered when it returns, so the mapping between packets and messages may not exist.

Nevertheless, knowing which message failed to send should be possible, even when you did not write the application-level protocol, and cannot change the standard to support acknowledgements. If the sender is keeping state as described above, it can determine which message failed to send on its own.

Does Netty provide an API for verifying that a message has been received? If not, can Netty support this functionality? In my case it would be sufficient to know which execution of a send operation failed (as opposed to being told which message failed). That is to say, I would be happy with any mechanism (e.g., an identifier) that allowed me to tie a send failure/success notification to the particular call to send.

Comment: A TCP ack does not mean a message was delivered & read by the application,only that the network stack has received it. The actual application might be stuck, while the network offloading still buffers the packet. This problem is also in existing protocols like SMTP where there is a critical moment where the client can think the message is not send, while the server has received the message

Comment: Thanks for your response! At this point, I just want to confirm that all the bytes of a message reach the next hop. Given that the application protocol doesn't support acknowledgements, I don't think I can do better.

Comment: To clarify, by next hop, I mean the next hop's operating system, not necessarily the application.